# IPSec: is it possible to check that a packet passed via IPSec tunnel?

Tags: ipsec

In our deployment we have two servers. I want to connect it via host to host VPN: [Host-To-Host VPN Using Openswan](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/Host-To-Host_VPN_Using_Openswan.html)

On one server we have JMS broker on the second server we have JMS client and I want allow access to JMS broker only if it is pass via IPSec channel (JMS broker and client is only for the example).

Is it possible to check that packets pass via IPSec channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter packets based on specific fields ipsec. For example, you can use the different modules offered by iptables with the -m option or --match:

- policy
- ha
- esp
- IP Sources and destination tunnel

http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables, see Match extensions

> **policy**
>
> This modules matches the policy used by IPsec for handling a packet.
>
> **--dir in|out**
>
> Used to select whether to match the policy used for decapsulation or the policy that will be used for encapsulation. in is valid in the
> PREROUTING, INPUT and FORWARD chains, out is valid in the POSTROUTING,
> OUTPUT and FORWARD chains.
>
> **--pol none|ipsec**
>
> Matches if the packet is subject to IPsec processing.
>
> **--strict**
>
> Selects whether to match the exact policy or match if any rule of the policy matches the given policy.
>
> **--reqid id**
>
> Matches the reqid of the policy rule. The reqid can be specified with setkey(8) using unique:id as level.
>
> **--spi spi**
>
> Matches the SPI of the SA.
>
> **--proto ah|esp|ipcomp**
>
> Matches the encapsulation protocol.
>
> **--mode tunnel|transport**
>
> Matches the encapsulation mode.
>
> **--tunnel-src addr[/mask]**
>
> Matches the source end-point address of a tunnel mode SA. Only valid with --mode tunnel.
>
> **--tunnel-dst addr[/mask]**
>
> Matches the destination end-point address of a tunnel mode SA. Only valid with --mode tunnel.
>
> **--next**
>
> Start the next element in the policy specification. Can only be used
> with --strict